# How can i stored and retrieve an array value using firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

That's the code that i am using:- i am trying to update existing user listen track time but  can't understand how to deal with array (to fetch data from database)

```
function update() {
  calculateTime(lap);
  console.log("update");
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();

  var updates = {
    code: code,
    date_db: date,
    time: time,
    mobile: mobile,
    listen_track: [timearr]
  }

  database.ref('listener/' + mobile).update(updates);
  alert('MANAN BHARNE KE LIYE CLICK KARE')
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Which part of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do? --- It might *also* help, if you show the current data at `/listener/$mobile` and the value of `timearr`.

Answer (score 0):

first I think you need to understand that firestore is a document DB, so through the API, you can update the whole document (put) and just some fields as you are doing.

For array fields, you need to think. What do I want to do with my values? Do you want to add new fields to the existing ones? Do you want to replace them?

For handling these options you can use the arrayUnion, or arrayRemove respectively.

You can do something like:

```
const unionRes = await database.ref('listener/' + mobile).update({
  listen_track : FieldValue.arrayUnion('greater_virginia')
});
```

In the next link you can check how to handle this behavior:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-array-operations?
hl=en-419#firestore_data_set_array_operations-nodejs

Comment: OP is using the Realtime Database, not Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate. The Realtime Database stores JSON, not documents, and doesn't have a `arrayUnion` operator.

Comment: I thought it was Cloud Firestore.